# Android 2.3.6 support library v7 option menu is missing

Tags: android

I'm using samsung  gt-s5570i 
[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [jawal123.com](http://jawal123.com/MobilesImages/BigImages/250/-471741899_27492.jpg))</sub>

as you can see the screen is small.
the OS is Android 2.3.6.
I want to create an app with action bar and menu (the three dots on the right side on the bar) using the support library v7 so i'll have backward compatibility .

my prblem is, the action bar is shown but the option menu is missing, I tried to run the same code on api 17 and it worked.

I dont know whats the problem, is it the resolution? or too old api?

thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    ActionBar ab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          ab = getSupportActionBar();
            ab.setTitle("Test");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add("Normal item");
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the device has a MENU button. Press the MENU button to access the overflow. This is [standard behavior](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) for the API Level 11+ action bar, and so I would expect the action bar backport to behave the same.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It would have been nice if this was in the Android Developer website somewhere, maybe I missed it.  I'm just getting started with Android Dev so the support library part does make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, if your device have hardware MENU button, you will not see 3 dots for menu. They appear if device have that "previous" apps button. So don't worry, it will work.